# dc.js - how to handle overlapping dots in line-charts?

Tags: dc.js

I have a composite chart that contains multiple line charts. However, many dots (points) overlap, causing only the last added line chart dots to be displayed. When hovering over the keys in the legend, only the lines are brought forward/highlighted, not the dots. So for any line charts with only one point and no line it is impossible to see the location of that point.

My current solution is to give each line chart a different dot radius in increasing order since I know the order in which each line chart will be added to the composite chart and it seems that the order dictates the stacking position of the lines/dots. This ends up looking clunky:

[image: clunky dot radius example]

Another, similar, approach I thought of was to set the fill-opacity to 0 and stroke-opacity to 1 for a cleaner presentation, but [there is an issue with stroke not being set.](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1447)

Are there any options/methods I may have missed in the library for handling this case of overlapping points? Thanks!

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to bring the dots to the front on hovering the legend. This can probably be done with a renderlet, although it probably belongs in the library too. Would this be acceptable to you? Thanks for your contribution btw, hope to review soon!

Comment: Yea, that seems like it would solve the issue. I'll see if can get it working/open a PR for it.